# How to even find a question to ask?

Tags: discussion

Just looking to post my first question in meta and after many many attempts at something remotely interesting

1. How to use small text
2. What is the exact requirements for `<this or that>` badge
3. Can `<x>` badge be earned multiple times
4. I have an idea for a badge (it's been tabled)
   etc

So my question is, how do you even find a new question to ask after everything has already been asked and the FAQ is full, badge roster is getting long enough etc.

I'm getting nowhere with asking questions here.

Note: I'm not even asking about [good questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45955/is-it-getting-harder-to-ask-good-questions), just normal, run of the mill questions!

Comment: Is this question supposed to be ironic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't ask a question for the sake of asking a question.

If you don't have one, don't ask one. Why would you?

Comment: +1 Keep the noise out

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Ask about a feature you'd like implemented.
- Ask about a bug you've found.
- Ask about a corner case of the system you've stumbled upon.
- Ask about unicorns.